# How do I replace a char in a dict in python

Tags: python

I have this tree in dictionary:

```
tree = {"'name': 'mass_index', 'direction': '>=', 'threshold': '27.8', 'children'": [0.0,
  {"'name': 'age', 'direction': '>=', 'threshold': '30.0', 'children'": [{"'name': 'mass_index', 'direction': '>=', 'threshold': '41.5', 'children'": [0.0,
      1.0]},
    1.0]}]}

type(tree)
dict
```

how can I replace `0.0` with `'{false}'` and `1.0` with `'{true}'` and remove all `"`. I couldn't find how to replace a char in dict and not the whole dict value. In a string is easy I can just do `value = value.replace('1.0', 'True')` or `value = value.replace('"', '')`  but how can one do it in a dict?
I would highly appreciate any help.

EDIT(this is the part that produces the dict):

```
feature_name = COLUMN_HEADERS[split_column]
    type_of_feature = FEATURE_TYPES[split_column]
    if type_of_feature == "continuous":
        question = "'cues': '{}', 'directions': '>=', 'thresholds': '{}', 'children'".format(feature_name, split_value)
        
    # feature is categorical
    else:
        question = "'cues': '{}', 'directions': '>=', 'thresholds': '{}', 'children'".format(feature_name, split_value)
    
    # instantiate sub-tree
    sub_tree = {question: []}
```

Comment: Right now, `"'name': 'mass_index', 'direction': '>=', 'threshold': '27.8', 'children'"` is the key for the dictionary. Did you want each key value pair to be separate?

Comment: @Dash yes actually.

Comment: What was the source of this tree?

Comment: I produce it myself, I will add in my initial post the part that is responsible for producing this dict.

Comment: I added an answer to generate a better tree. What does the tree look like now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about converting the dict to a string then replace using `regex`. Then after, convert it back to a dictionary.

Sample:

```py
import re
tree = {"'name': 'mass_index', 'direction': '>=', 'threshold': '27.8', 'children'": [0.0,
{"'name': 'age', 'direction': '>=', 'threshold': '30.0', 'children'": [{"'name': 'mass_index', 'direction': '>=', 'threshold': '41.5', 'children'": [0.0,
      1.0]},
    1.0]}]}

treeStr = str(tree)
    
treeStr = re.sub(r'\[0.0,', '[\'false\',', treeStr)
treeStr  = re.sub(r'\, 0.0]', ', \'false\']', treeStr)

treeStr = re.sub(r'\[1.0,', '[\'true\',', treeStr)
treeStr = re.sub(r'\, 1.0]', ', \'true\']', treeStr) 
    
import ast
treeDict = ast.literal_eval(treeStr)

type(treeDict)
print(treeDict)
```

Comment: I guess it might work. But isn't it too much effort? Converting to string will be easy but idk how to convert it back to dict in this format. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: it's really easy but not sure if that is the best option though. Since the object is really a dictionary. You can do a treeStr = str(tree). Then for converting the string to dict, you can import ast, then do ast.literal_eval(treeStr)

Comment: This one actually works, but it changes `'30.0'` to `'3'{false}'` as well which I don't want. I want to strictly replace only when `0.0`

Comment: See my updated answer with regex to replace the numbers

Comment: thank you so much! I tried with regex myself as well but without success. Your solution worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a dict from the get-go for your tree, instead of using `str.format()`

This should allow you to iterate through your dict and replace the undesired values.

```py
feature_name = COLUMN_HEADERS[split_column]
type_of_feature = FEATURE_TYPES[split_column]
question = {'directions': '>='}
if type_of_feature == "continuous":
    question['cues'] = feature_name
    question['thresholds'] = split_value

# I can't see any reason why this if statement is here, but I'll leave it if there's other things you add
else:   # feature is categorical
    question['cues'] = feature_name
    question['thresholds'] = split_value
    
    # instantiate sub-tree
sub_tree = {question: []}
```

Comment: thank you! This actually might work better. But the problem is that you have not included `'children'` and I also get an error now saying:  `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` in `sub_tree = {question: []}`